# Flutter snapshot.data.length return wrong value

Tags: json, flutter

Below is my example snapshot.data.length return 2 but in my example is 15 what is wrong here?

```
    class ApiService {
      static Future<dynamic> _get(String url) async {
        try {
          final response = await http.get(url);
          var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
            return jsonData;
          }
      }

      static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getUserList() async {
        return await _get('${Urls.BASE_API_URL}');
      }

.........
          body: FutureBuilder(
            future: ApiService.getUserList(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                final posts = snapshot.data;
                print(posts.length);  //Return 2
```

Json URL:  http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cqwVqdOFrC?indent=2

Comment: Maybe two is because you have "items" and "first" elements ? You probably need to select `items.length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's 2 not 15

```
 {"items":[],"first":[]}
```

if you want the items only

```
  final posts = snapshot.data["items"];
                print(posts.length);
```

It will be 15